# How to point from one module to the next

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a password system for a program. I have the first half working so when I punch in the code it opens my file. After that the program asks for the password again instead of moving on to the next module which is supposed to close the file. Here's what I have

```
import os
while True:
    choice = int(input("Enter Password: "))
    if (choice>=1124):
        if choice ==1124:
             try:
                os.startfile('C:\\restriced access')

             except Exception as e:
                print (str(e))

while True:
    choice = int(input("Close? (y/n): "))
    if (choice<='y'):
        if choice =='y':
                    os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM C:\\restriced access')
```

I want it to kind of appear as an "if/then" kinda statement. For example if the password is entered correctly it opens the file `os.startfile('C:\restriced access') then points to the next module to give the option to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"While True" just keeps looping infinitely. As soon as you open the file it'll go back to the beginning of that loop and ask for your password again. If you want it to break from that loop if they get the password correct you need to add a "break" after your startfile line. I'm also not sure why you check their password twice. If you want it to exit the loop after attempting to open the file whether it succeeds or not, add a "finally" block after your exception handler.

```
while True:
    choice = int(input("Enter Password: "))
    if (choice>=1124):
        if choice ==1124:
             try:
                os.startfile('C:\\restriced access')
                break
             except Exception as e:
                print (str(e))
```

Comment: thank you i just started learning like 2 days ago so im trying to understand how it works i googled a few different programs and im patchworking them to get the hang of it

Comment: No worries: Hope it continues to go well

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is `while True:`. This will never exit unless you explicitly exit from it. You want to add a `break` in it like so:

```
os.startfile('C:\\restriced access')
break
```

Answer (score 0):

Great to see you learn python.
The reason is because the while loop doesn't have a break in it.

Then again avoid opening files in a loop.
Also the nested if makes it hard to debug.

Also checkout pep8.

havent made any code changes.

```
import os 
while True: 
    choice = int(input("Enter Password: "))     

   if (choice<1124): 
       continue

   if choice ==1124: 
        try: os.startfile('C:\\restriced access') 
             break
        except Exception as e: 
             print (str(e)) 
             break

while True:
    choice = input("Close? (y/n): ")
    if (choice=='y'):
          break
```

Comment: ok thank you. any ideas on how to make the next part work @Nick Maina

Comment: @Kailaugen which part? The close? ooh and for passwords python has a lib for that `import getpass` then `passwd = getpass.getpass()`

Comment: can you give me an example of how the password would work please